# Question about the impedance of a RLC circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, frequency, inductance

I made an experiment with a RLC circuit, and I found the resistance, the capacitance, and the inductance with measures. So I decided to calculate the impedance of the circuit, depending on the frequency with the formula :
$$Z_{RLC}=\sqrt{\left(R+R_L\right)^2+\left(\omega L-\dfrac{1}{\omega C}\right)^2}$$
Where $R$ is the resistance [$\Omega$], $R_L$ is the resistance of the inductor [$\Omega$], $\omega$ [rad/s] is equal to $2\pi f$ and $f$ is the frequency [Hz], $L$ is the inductance [H] and $C$ is the capacitance [F].

I plot the data, with $R=34.6\; \Omega$, $R_L=27.2\;\Omega$, $L=0.04691103\;H$ and $C=4.8873\cdot 10^{-5}\;F$ :

[image]

As this is based on measures, I add uncertainties. So the formula for $Z_{RLC}$ with the maximum uncertainty is :
$$Z_{RLC}=\sqrt{\left(R+R_i+R_L+R_{Li}\right)^2+\left(\omega (L+L_i)-\dfrac{1}{\omega (C+C_i)}\right)^2}$$
Where $R_i$ is the uncertainty of the resistance [$\Omega$], $R_{Li}$ is the uncertainty of the resistance of the inductor [$\Omega$], $L_i$ is the uncertainty of the inductance [H] and $C_i$ is the uncertainty of the capacitance [F].
And the formula for $Z_{RLC}$ with the minimum uncertainty is :
$$Z_{RLC}=\sqrt{\left(R-R_i+R_L-R_{Li}\right)^2+\left(\omega (L-L_i)-\dfrac{1}{\omega (C-C_i)}\right)^2}$$
I plot $Z_{RLC}$ with the maximum uncertainty and with the minimum uncertainty, with $R_i=0.005\; \Omega=R_{Li}$, $L_i = 0.00536475\; H$ and $C_i=3.4444\cdot 10^{-7}\; F$ :

[image]

Where the blue curve is $Z_{RLC}$ with the maximum uncertainty and the red curve is $Z_{RLC}$ with the minimum uncertainty.

We don't see it in the graph, but before the resonance frequency $Z_{RLC}$ with the maximum uncertainty is lower than $Z_{RLC}$ and conversely for $Z_{RLC}$ with the minimum uncertainty. This is the case until the resonance frequency where $Z_{RLC}$ with the maximum uncertainty becomes bigger than $Z_{RLC}$ and conversely for $Z_{RLC}$ with the minimum uncertainty.

I don't why at first $Z_{RLC}$ with the maximum uncertainty is lower than $Z_{RLC}$ and conversely for $Z_{RLC}$ with the minimum uncertainty. Does anyone have an answer?

**EDIT**

As requested in the comments, I plot the 8 ways to combine min and max values to calculate max deviation of Z. The 8 ways are : (Rmin, Lmin, Cmin), (Rmin, Lmin, Cmax), (Rmin, Lmax, Cmin), (Rmin, Lmax, Cmax), (Rmax, Lmin, Cmin), (Rmax, Lmin, Cmax), (Rmax, Lmax, Cmin), and (Rmax, Lmax, Cmax).

[image]

Where the orange curve is the combination (Rmax, Lmin, Cmax) and the olive curve is the combination (Rmax, Lmax, Cmin).

We don't see it on the graph but the combinations are superimposed.

So this don't change my question.

Comment: In my opinion there would be eight ways to combine min and max values to calculate max deviation of Z: (Rmin, Lmin, Cmin), (Rmin, Lmin, Cmax), (Rmin, Lmax, Cmin), (Rmin, Lmax, Cmax), (Rmax, Lmin, Cmin), (Rmax, Lmin, Cmax), (Rmax, Lmax, Cmin), and, (Rmax, Lmax, Cmax). I may be wrong, but I would've plot all 8 curves.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but I assume; why at low frequency is there little deviation while at high frequency greater deviation. I would say that the values of R, L, and C are relatively small... even when they are squared. Whereas Frequency  ranges from small to large values. When you square a small frequency value the result is relatively small even with small tolerances combined. When you square a larger frequency value and include the tolerances of the smaller values (Lmax, Cmin) and (Lmin, Cmax) the resulting variations are greater.

Comment: Also (in my opinion), the coefficients of charging, the rates of transfer, and the burn off of energy through resistance limit the response that is driven by current / voltage relationships. You can see the effect of frequency is driven primarily by L and C (ELI the ICE man).